# Odd behavior when adding class instance to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Suppose I have this class set up

```
class X:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.friends = []

  def addFriend(self, name):
    self.friends.append(name)

  def getFriends(self):
    return self.friends    

joe = X('joe')
tom = X('tom')
joe.addFriend(tom)
joe.getFriends()
```

When I call joe.getFriends() I'm expecting to get `[tom]`.  Instead I'm getting the following

```
[<__main__.X at 0x25eb81187f0>]
```

I think I'm missing something really simple so I need some pointers in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: You did not tell Python to display instances of `X` as the value of the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To specify how your class instance is represented, define the `__repr__` method:

```py
class X:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.friends = []

  def addFriend(self, name):
    self.friends.append(name)

  def getFriends(self):
    return self.friends    

  def __repr__(self):
      return self.name


joe = X('joe')
tom = X('tom')
joe.addFriend(tom)
joe.getFriends()
```

Output:

```
[tom]
```

---

This also works for `print`:

```py
print(tom)
```

Output:

```
tom
```